# Django modal Update with preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

Hi Im trying to change some parts from a existung project.

The existing project is is from Github here:
https://github.com/AliBigdeli/Django-Smart-RFID-Access-Control/

I added in Card management one new field in models.py

```
class UIDCard(models.Model):
    ...
    ammount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    ...
```

Also added in the folder **dashboard/api/serializers.py** the price in **class CardReaderSerializer**

Now I changed some parts in **templates/card-management.html**

- Added the field "ammount" in the genral overview, is showing me the Database value
- Added a Pay button, open a new Modal window, the plan is to add some money on it. The enterred value is saving on the Database, but with two issues.

first, I cant see the existing values from the Database in the formfields prefilled. Like in the edit part
second, the Update button is saving the value but the modal window is not closing

I cant find the problems in the code, can somewhre helping me please

The complete changed .html file:

```
{% extends 'dashboard/base.html'%}

{% block content %}
<div class="d-flex">
    <div>
        <h1 class="mt-4">Cards</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-auto mt-4">
        <button type="button " class="btn btn-warning" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#CreateFormModal"
            id="CreateDevice">
            Add Card ID
        </button>
    </div>
</div>


<hr>
<div class="table-responsive" style="height: 100%;">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="table-dark">

            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Card ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Ammount</th>
                <th scope="col">Gateway</th>
                <th scope="col">Access</th>
                <th scope="col">Actions</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody id="table-item-wrapper">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- Create Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="CreateFormModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="FormModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="FormModalLabel">Create Form</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="create-form">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Card ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="card_id">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Ammount:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ammount">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="GatewaySelect">Gateway</label>
                        <select class="form-control GatewaySelect" name="gateway" >
                            
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="AccessSelect">Access</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="access">
                            <option value="1">Authorized</option>
                            <option value="2">UnAuthorized</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" id="ModalFooter">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Create</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Edit Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="EditFormModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="FormModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="FormModalLabel">Create Form</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="edit-form">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="FormModalName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Card ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="card_id" id="FormModalCardID">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Ammount:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ammount" id="FormModalAmmount">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="GatewaySelect">Gateway</label>
                        <select class="form-control GatewaySelect" name="gateway" id="FormModalGateway">
                            
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="AccessSelect">Access</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="access" id="FormModalAccess">
                            <option value="1">Authorized</option>
                            <option value="2">UnAuthorized</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" id="ModalFooter">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Pay Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="PayFormModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="FormModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="FormModalLabel">Pay Form</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="pay-form">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="FormModalName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Card ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="card_id" id="FormModalCardID">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Ammount:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ammount" id="FormModalAmmount">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="GatewaySelect">Gateway</label>
                        <select class="form-control GatewaySelect" name="gateway" id="FormModalGateway">

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="AccessSelect">Access</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="access" id="FormModalAccess">
                            <option value="1">Authorized</option>
                            <option value="2">UnAuthorized</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" id="ModalFooter">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




{% endblock content %}



{% block extra_js %}
<script>
    var host_url = location.protocol + '//' + location.host
    var main_url = new URL(host_url + "/dashboard/api/card-id/")
    var general_id

    function fetchGatewayData(){
        let wrapper = $('.GatewaySelect')
        $.get("/dashboard/api/card-reader/",  // url
            function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                results_data = data
                wrapper.empty()
                results_data.forEach(function (item, i) {
                    // for (post of data.results) {
                    wrapper.append(`<option value="${item.id}" >${item.name}</option>`)
                }


                )
            })
    }

    function fetchData(url) {
        let wrapper = $('#table-item-wrapper')

        $.get(url,  // url
            function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                results_data = data
                wrapper.empty()
                results_data.forEach(function (item, i) {
                    // for (post of data.results) {
                    wrapper.append(`<tr id='table-item-${item.id}'>                
                            <td>${i += 1}</td>
                            <td>${item.name}</td>
                            <td>${item.card_id}</td>
                            <td>${item.ammount} €</td>
                            <td>${item.gateway.name}</td>
                            <td>${item.access.name}</td>
                            <td style="width:20%">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" onclick="openPayModal(${item.id})" >Pay</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" onclick="openEditModal(${item.id})" >Edit</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="button" onclick="removeItem(${item.id})">Delete</button>                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>`)
                }


                )
            })

    }

    $("#create-form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        // console.log(this.job_title.value)
        // console.log('sent')
        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', this.name.value)
        formData.append('gateway', this.gateway.value)
        formData.append('card_id', this.card_id.value)
        formData.append('ammount', this.ammount.value)
        formData.append('access', this.access.value)

        $.ajax({
            // contentType: "multipart/form-data",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            },
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
            url: "/dashboard/api/card-id/",
            success: function (data) {
                fetchData(main_url)
                $('#create-form').trigger("reset");
                $("#CreateFormModal").modal('hide');
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response)
            }
        });
    });


    $("#edit-form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', this.name.value)
        formData.append('gateway', this.gateway.value)
        formData.append('ammount', this.ammount.value)
        formData.append('card_id', this.card_id.value)
        formData.append('access', this.access.value)
        let id = general_id
        $.ajax({
            // contentType: "multipart/form-data",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            },
            type: 'PATCH',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
            url: `/dashboard/api/card-id/${id}/`,
            success: function (data) {
                fetchData(main_url)
                $('#edit-form').trigger("reset");
                $("#EditFormModal").modal('hide');
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response)
            }
        });
    });


    $("#pay-form").submit(function (f) {
        f.preventDefault()
        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', this.name.value)
        formData.append('gateway', this.gateway.value)
        formData.append('ammount', this.ammount.value)
        formData.append('card_id', this.card_id.value)
        formData.append('access', this.access.value)
        let id = general_id
        $.ajax({
            // contentType: "multipart/form-data",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            },
            type: 'PATCH',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
            url: `/dashboard/api/card-id/${id}/`,
            success: function (data) {
                fetchData(main_url)
                $('#pay-form').trigger("reset");
                $("#PayFormModal").modal('hide');
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response)
            }
        });
    });





    function openEditModal(id) {
        $("#EditFormModal").modal('show');
        general_id = id
        modal = document.getElementById("EditFormModal")
        let result_data
        $.get(`/dashboard/api/card-id/${id}/`,
            function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                result_data = data
                // console.log(result_data.text)

            }).then(function () {
                console.log(result_data)
                $('#FormModalName').val(result_data.name)
                $('#FormModalCardID').val(result_data.card_id)
                $('#FormModalAmmount').val(result_data.ammount)
                $('#FormModalGateway').val(result_data.gateway.id)
                $('#FormModalAccess').val(result_data.access.id)

            })
    }


    function openPayModal(id) {
        $("#PayFormModal").modal('show');
        general_id = id
        modal = document.getElementById("PayFormModal")
        let result_data
        $.get(`/dashboard/api/card-id/${id}/`,
            function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                result_data = data
                // console.log(result_data.text)

            }).then(function () {
                console.log(result_data)
                $('#FormModalName').val(result_data.name)
                $('#FormModalCardID').val(result_data.card_id)
                $('#FormModalAmmount').val(result_data.ammount)
                $('#FormModalGateway').val(result_data.gateway.id)
                $('#FormModalAccess').val(result_data.access.id)

            })
    }



    function removeItem(id) {
        if (confirm(`Are you sure you want to remove this ${id} id?`)) {
            $.ajax({
                // contentType: "multipart/form-data",
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
                },
                type: 'DELETE',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                url: `/dashboard/api/card-id/${id}/`,
                success: function (data) {
                    fetchData(main_url)
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response)
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(error);
                }

            });
        } else {

        }
    }


    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
        url = main_url
        fetchData(url)
        fetchGatewayData()

        // fetchJobTitles()
    });
</script>
{% endblock extra_js %}
```

In console log, the fields are visible with the Values. BUt not in the modal prefilled